# Exponer servicio web con REST y SOAP con el mismo método

Tags: java, rest, soap, jboss, jboss-eap

Estoy intentando exponer un servicio usando las APIs de servicios de web de SOAP y Restful (jax-rs and jax-ws). Actualmente he logrado (solo con anotaciones JAX-*) que se publique el servicio web tanto en REST como SOAP.

Esto es interesante para no duplicar métodos y para tener mayor flexibilidad de la API que se desea exponer.

```
@Path("/alertas")
@WebService
public class AlertasApi  {
...
@GET   
@Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
@Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
@WebMethod
public Alertas listarAlertas() {
return alertasService.listarAlertas();
};
...
```

Los servicios se publican en un servidor JBOSS EAP 7.0.0 sin necesidad de configuración extra, es decir, no he tenido que configurar ningún XML.

En el servidor simplemente se publica la API y el sitio web generado por Maven.

Sé que Apache CXF permite la gestión de SOAP y REST por lo que en principio sería la primera opción. También el propio JBOSS tiene una implementación basada en CXF llamada JBOSSWS-CXF.

Como los siguientes pasos a seguir es la autenticación y la autorización tendría que ver que API es la más acertada para mantener el código lo más simple posible.

El problema que me encuentro es que no veo documentación alguna para utilizar CXF con servicios web REST y SOAP al mismo tiempo y hacerlo con el JBOSS EAP (hay un tutorial con Spring).

En mi proyecto Maven tengo la siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
 <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
 <version>${version.jboss.spec.javaee.7.0}</version>
 <type>pom</type>
 <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Esto me carga todos las dependecias necesarias pero no veo ni rastro de CXF o JBOSSWS, las cuales existen en el directorio de módulos del EAP. A su vez me carga *resteasy*, el cual no deseo utilizar.

En resumen, tengo:

- JBOSS EAP 7.0.0 haciendo un deploy de un WAR para microservicios REST y SOAP (el mismo servicio)
- Uso Maven para la dependencias del proyecto
- Deseo aplicar seguridad en los servicios (ambos)
- Deseo que sea lo más simple posible, preferiblemente con anotaciones y que la misma configuración aplique a ambos

¿Cuál creen que es la mejor solución en este caso?

Comment: Mi recomendación es que te apegues al las especificaciones de JAX-RS, JAX-WS y JAVAEE, no ates tu proyecto a CXF o a JBOSS.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, el problema es que quiero desarrollar una API y exponer sus métodos tanto en REST como en SOAP. Por eso quiero utilizar CXF, es decir, no me gustaría implementar la seguridad y funcionalidad de los métodos en paralelo. Un saludo.